# Linked list Move constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, move-constructor

I am trying to write a move constructor for a double linked list, but its not working. Can someone help me find what I am doing wrong?

Here is my class:

```
class SortedList {
    struct Node {
        T data_;
        Node* next_;
        Node* prev_;
        Node(const T& data = T{}, Node* nx = nullptr, Node* pr = nullptr) {
            data_ = data;
            next_ = nx;
            prev_ = pr;
        }
    };

    Node* front_;
    Node* back_;
    int sizelist;
}
```

And here is my move constructor:

```
SortedList<T>::SortedList(SortedList&& rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
        sizelist = rhs.sizelist;
        front_ = rhs.front_;
        back_ = rhs.back_;  

        Node* head = rhs.front_;    
        Node* headNext =rhs.front_->next_;      
        for (int i = 0; i < rhs.sizelist-1; i++) {
            head = nullptr;
            head = headNext;            
            headNext = headNext->next_;         
        }
        rhs.sizelist = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you draw an instance of the linked list on a piece of paper, then draw what the move assignment should do.

Comment: User-provided constructors must be declared in the class definition; and `T` is not defined in `SortedList`. Please post real code

Comment: "It's not working" is not a useful problem description. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should take ownership of the data from the old object, and make the old object an empty list.
There is no point in testing for "self-copying" in a move constructor.

```
SortedList<T>::SortedList(SortedList&& rhs)
{
    sizelist = rhs.sizelist;
    rhs.sizeList = 0;
    front_ = rhs.front_;
    rhs.front_ = nullptr;
    back_ = rhs.back_;
    rhs.back_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Is invalidating the old object necessary? Aren't we assumimg that moved object won't be ever used/reached by user?

Comment: @Fureeish You definitely don't want to *invalidate* the original object. It must be left in a valid state, since it's at least going to be destroyed later, and may even be used. The simplest valid state for a container is usually the empty state.